# SQL TOP 1 returning null when used in a sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

Please can you help with this sub query - it works fine I run it by itself for one client but returns null when added to the query.

For each client I need to get the employee with the most orders.

This is part of a much bigger query so performance is also an issue.

```
SELECT c.ClientId, s.BestEmployeeId 
FROM client c
LEFT OUTER JOIN(
SELECT TOP 1 o.EmployeeId AS BestEmployeeId, count(o.EmployeeId) AS cnt, o.ClientId
    FROM Orders o
    WHERE o.EmployeeId > 0
    AND o.EmployeeId is not null    
    GROUP BY o.ClientId, o.EmployeeId
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
) AS s on c.ClientId = s.ClientId
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For each client I need to get the employee with the most orders.

I would do this with aggregation and window functions:

```
select oc.*
from (select o.client, o.employeeid, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (partition by o.client order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from Orders o
      group by o.client, o.employeeid
     ) oc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that you don't seem to need the `client` table, because `orders` appears to have both `client` and `employeeid`.

Your version is filtering out `NULL` values of `employeeid`.  You can do this in the subquery as well (although your problem statement says nothing about such values).

Comment: Many thanks Gordon, but I do need the client table as my main query is all about the client - as I mentioned this is just a small part of a much bigger query.  Yogesh's answer has worked well.

Comment: It took me a while to get my head around the partition but this has halved the time it takes to run my query.  Thank you Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` for that

```
SELECT c.ClientId, b.BestEmployeeId 
FROM client c OUTER APPLY (
       SELECT TOP 1 o.EmployeeId AS BestEmployeeId
       FROM Orders o
       WHERE o.ClientId = c.ClientId AND o.EmployeeId > 0
       GROUP BY o.EmployeeId
       ORDER BY count(o.EmployeeId) DESC
   ) b;
```

Comment: Perfect, and easy to understand.  Thank you

Comment: Easy and clear solution!